# Where is size, make equal in Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm sure, in past versions of Visio, there used to be an option where you could select a bunch of shapes, and select size, make equal.  Somewhere around the Align and Position tabs on the Home menu.

It's possible I'm confusing visio with Visual Studio, which I believe does have this option in the design screen.

Is there such an option in Visio? It would be so useful - I don't want to actually have to type in a size for the shape - I just want them all to be the same size, preferably able to select whether I mean horizontal size, vertical size or both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Size and Position window (menu **View** -> **Task Panes**).
Select the shapes you want, then to change the width of them all just types in a new width.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for that.  I saw your post on this at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/daee2414-d904-4c12-a0d5-f52ed80fe00f/visio-2010-how-to-make-objects-same-size-as-each-other?forum=visiogeneral  The thing is, though, I don't want to have to specify the actual size.  I want to be able to say: "Make all these things the same size as the first one I selected.", just like I can in Visual Studio.  Can we ask Microsoft to include this in the next release?

Comment: Visual Studio's form designer is in many ways far simpler that Visio, an item placed on a form has a width and height specified in pixels relative to the form, and that is it,  Visio is a lot more complicated than that. The width and height can be a formula which may be dependent on other aspects of the shape, or another shape(s), or dependent on the page, or shapes on another page! I have written some Visio utilities, http://www.paulherber.co.uk/visio-utilities/ , and I would be loath to add a feature like this as there would be so many ways for it to not do what what wanted.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, Paul.  It helps to know why a feature is not available.  I will just suck it up and specify exact sizes in future!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the F4 key to duplicate the last keystroke for instance, if you choose a shape, put in the height that you want, then choose the next shape and hit the F4 key, it will duplicate the same height, then you won't have to physically type the change for each item - hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but the newest version of Visual Studio allows you to do this without hitting F4. Select the objects, go to View > Task Pans > Size & Position, and adjust as necessary. All objects will change together.

Comment: The question is about MS Visio, not about MS Visual Studio.